# Will a faster lens help getting a better (faster/more accurate) focus?

Tags: lens, autofocus

I read that with some cameras (but which?), using an f/2.8 lens or faster enables a more sensitive phase AF point, so there is quantum jump in AF accuracy.

But that's not really my question :) My question is whether I can expect some AF improvement between an f/5.6 lens and an f/4 one, since the standard AF points will have more aperture and light to work with?

Comment: I would guess that it depends on the amount of ambient light and the specs of the autofocus sensors, at least, that's how *my* autofocus (aka manual focus) seems to work. I've also noticed difficulties associated with increased depth of field. The smaller the aperture, the more equally focused/blurry everything starts to look.

Comment: A problem with *some* lenses with big apertures is everything can be blurry because of various aberrations, so it's impossible to *really* focus on anything. Also, depth of field can be too narrow, making it hard to lock focus on anything. The sweet spot where the amount of light, contrast, and depth of field is optimal probably depends on the specific lens and sensors involved.

Comment: The answers to the duplicate are also applicable to the differences between f/5.6 and f/4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aperture in relation to PDAF relates to whether the required image (objective lens) area can be seen by the PDAF module and *not* the amount of light the module receives.

The AF module receives light equivalent to approximately f/7 due to its' own aperture restrictions, so having a wider lens aperture does not transmit more light to the module. Having a lens of f/2.8 or wider is only of a benefit if the camera is designed to use the f/2.8 objective areas... i.e. some Canon models like the 1Dx have f/2.8 "helper" focus points (initial focus is with f/5.6 points and then refined using the f/2.8 points).

If this is in relation to on-image-sensor focus, then yes... every bit of extra light/contrast helps.

Comment: The equivalent f-number an AF module receives varies greatly from one camera to the next. The "approximately f/7" quote is from a [DPR discussion in which Marianne Oelund is referring to a *specific* camera](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3713509) and in the same discussion she also acknowledges that other cameras have different effective f-numbers!

Comment: Please see the answers and comments to [Does autofocus work better with f/2.8 lenses vs f/4 or slower?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47122/15871) for a fuller discussion of this errant claim.

Comment: The simple fact is that the PDAF module uses small images taken from small areas of the objective lens which creates a "virtual aperture" as discussed in the DPR article. It simply cannot be equivalent to the lens' max aperture.

AFAIK, *all* PDAF systems are designed primarily around an f/5.6 lens aperture so that there will be no shading/vignetting/light loss at f/5.6 or wider... i.e. f/5.6 is the maximum light potential to the module. Some have additional points that can use the f/8 or f/2.8 objective areas, but that has no effect on the amount of light/size of the virtual apertures.

Comment: Only on-sensor AF uses the full objective lens area (aperture) cumulatively for autofocus...

Comment: That all depends on the lens' maximum aperture compared to the effective aperture of the PDAF system. In the case of an f/4 lens on a camera with some AF points sensitive to f/2.8, the lens is more restrictive than the microlenses and length of the lines on the PDAF sensor. Thus the lens is the more restrictive bottleneck. Why do you keep insisting on taking Marianne Oelund's comment regard *one specific camera* and universally applying it to all cameras, even when she herself stated later in the same discussion that other cameras' PDAF system can be, and sometimes are, wider?

Comment: There's no need to use the "full objective lens (aperture)..." in order to give a PDAF sensor (or some segments of it) an effective aperture wider than f/7 or f/5.6. One only need use two small areas from opposite sides of the lens' entrance pupil. That's how [PDAF systems](https://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/canon-7d-mark-ii/Z-7d2-65ptAF.jpg) work. It's why some AF points tuned for larger apertures (i.e f/2.8) don't work with lens with narrower apertures (i.e. f/4 or f/5.6 or f/8). The f/2.8 lines on the sensor only measure the light at the extreme edges of the lens.

Comment: Microlenses and phase lines for each AF "point" on a PDAF sensor module are independent of the other microlenses and sets of lines for other AF "points" in the same system. The length of each set of lines and the distance they are from one another, along with the design of the *specific* microlenses for each of those two lines collecting light from opposite sides of the lens determine the "effective aperture" of the PDAF system *for that specific AF "point"*. Just because Nikon once (but no longer does) tuned *every* AF point on their PDAF sensors to the same width does not mean everyone does.

Comment: This is the set of microlenses for a simple 9-point AF system. https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRpLacQmeTf3f4OcsRYduEKyulCxwBQl6u4cOvsedQToeg6_P1ivg

Comment: The [ten sets of diagonal lines widely spaced from one another](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTNNULfYXCJ8685NJtyDmD8yr42YkTeRJSYpQ135JigBJYfioTb) are for the [five diagonal "cross type" f/2.8 sensitive](https://media.the-digital-picture.com/Images/Other/Canon-EOS-7D-Mark-II/Canon-EOS-7D-II-1D-X-5D-III-AF-Point-Comparison.png) portions of the Canon EOS 1D X and 5D Mark III AF system.

Comment: [This chart](https://www.zacuto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/AF-sensor.jpg) further explains which AF points are tuned for which apertures. The microlenses do not restrict the "effective" aperture narrower for any of them.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are confusing aperture *location* with the *virtual aperture* which is what limits the amount of light available. The lens' aperture simply dictates wether the location of the virtual aperture (source image location) is visible or not.

This image is a simplified drawing of how the PDAF system works: https://photos.app.goo.gl/LHCL183cCT8Zk9tD7

Comment: Sorry, new link to annotated image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/w4pCTQwSiKbhD5rP8

Comment: I'm not confusing anything. I'm merely pointing out that your answer breeds confusion by appearing to assert that PDAF systems can not see any 'locations of the virtual aperture' that are outside of what is allowed through by a lens aperture of approximately f/7. That is not true. After all, the OP is asking what is the difference between an f/4 and an f/2.8 *lens*, not the difference between a *PDAF sensor* with microlenses that are effectively as bright as f/2.8 or f/4.

Comment: We just disagree... the aperture brightness is completely unrelated to the aperture location for a PDAF focus point.
The aperture related to a focus point is simply whether or not that area of the objective element can be seen beyond the aperture blade restriction.
You seem to understand that f/2.8 points are using separate images taken from the  periphery of an f/2.8 objective element, and the same is true for f/5.6 points and objective elements. And I'm sure you know that the f-ratio of a lens is limited by the objective element diameter...

Comment: The effective aperture (light) for a PDAF focus point is limited by the area of objective element where each image is taken from (and then compared for position/phase). It has nothing to do with a lens' max aperture.
I can concede that it may not be f/7 for all designs (I did say "approximately), but it is simply impossible for it equivalent the the diameter of the objective lens...

Answer (score 1):

Since most cameras focus with the lens wide open, a wider aperture allows the *possibility* of better AF performance. This is because the baseline between the light entering on opposite sides of the lens is wider.

But this potential can only be realized if the camera's AF system is designed to take advantage of it. Some cameras' AF systems are and some are not. **So ultimately, it depends on the particular camera.**

The following is primarily with regard to SLRs that have a dedicated PDAF sensor that is used when the camera's reflex mirror is down. Mirrorless cameras' main imaging sensor based AF systems are also affected by a lens' maximum aperture, but in different ways.

In general, the lines of demarcation are between f/5.6 and f/8 with respect to the minimum wide open aperture a lens can have and still allow a specific camera body to AF at all, and between f/4 and f/2.8 on the other end with regard to the minimum wide open aperture a lens needs to take advantage of the more sensitive sensors in a camera's AF system.

Many cameras require an f/5.6 or faster lens in order to AF at all, but there are some that can AF with an f/8 lens or combination of lens + teleconverter/extender. Most cameras that have some AF focus points that are more sensitive require f/2.8 or wider lenses in order for those points to function, but there are a few cameras that have PDAF sensors with a combination of f/2.8, f/4, and f/5.6 or f/8 lines on the AF sensor.

For a more complete discussion of how PDAF sensors work with lenses of various maximum apertures, including illustrations, please see [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/47124/15871) to: [Does autofocus work better with f/2.8 lenses vs f/4 or slower?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/47122/15871)

Comment: "*In general, the lines of demarcation are between f/5.6 and f/8 with respect to the minimum wide open aperture a lens can have and still allow a specific camera body to AF at all, and between f/4 and f/2.8 on the other end with regard to the minimum wide open aperture a lens needs to take advantage of the more sensitive sensors in a camera's AF system.*" My question is about that f/4-F5.6 range where you are only using "standard" AF sensors. For a given type of AF sensors, it there any advantage (AF-wise) to using a faster lens?

Comment: @xenoid As the answer clearly states: **It all depends on the design of a specific AF system.** Without knowing what camera you are asking about, it is impossible to answer that question. There's no such thing as a "standard" AF point. Every camera design can be, and often is, different.