# How do I select a single AF point with Canon EOS 100D

Tags: canon, focus-point-selection

In my last holidays I mistaken a lot of shots failing to focus the subject. For example when my son was inside a big tree, the multipoint AF got in focus the tree and not my son.

The EOS 100D manual says that to focus on a specific subject you need to activate the LCD screen and pick the relevant point.

I'm not comfortable with this. Is there any way to set one point AF and take pictures using the viewfinder on this camera?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to select one point and still use the viewfinder.

I am attaching the manual page.

[image: Canon 100d manual af point selection]

Just make sure that you are in one of the letter modes (e.g. select P on the top dial) otherwise this wont' work at all.

Comment: Does this mean I can focus on my son face, half-press the shutter button, reframe the picture and take the picture? I mean, avoiding to select the AF point and always using the central one.

Comment: Yes. But also be aware that even with only one focus point selected the camera will focus on the area of highest contrast within the active focus area. Most focus points have areas that are larger than their indicator squares in the viewfinder. Here's a link to an answer that discusses the similar AF map of the Canon EOS 5D Mark II: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/43813/15871

Comment: @Alberto, yes this is exactly how I work. 99% times I use the center point. See also the answer linked by Michael Clark for more details

Answer (score 1):

To select a single focus point simply press the button on the top right side, named the 'AF Point' button, then select the focus point using the arrow keys, finally press the [SET] button which is in-between the arrow keys.